# Java, animate a still image in a JApplet

Tags: java, swing, animation, japplet

I am working on an assignment and I'm essentially done with the assignment, it was just a simple program to create an image map and add some audio to hot spots, I have a couple more days left and was going to try and "animate" the image.

It's a picture of a car dash board and when the user clicked on the ignition I was going to see if there is a way to make the image shake for a second.  I've tried looking around here and on google but every time I searched I was getting articles from the 90's for applet's and not JApplet's.

If you could point my in the right direction on how to "animate" the image or even to a place where there may be tutorials I'd appreciate it!

Here is my code if you want to see what I'm talking about and can help me out in anyway.

```
public class ImageMap extends JApplet implements MouseListener{
   private Image pic;
   private Container contentPane;
   private JLabel directions;
   private Rectangle horn;
   private Rectangle vent;
   private Rectangle doorLocksUpper;
   private Rectangle window;
   private Rectangle radio;
   private Rectangle ignition;
   private int x, y;
   private AudioClip hornSound, airSound, radioClip, lockSound1, lockSound2, ignitionSound;

public void init() {        
    pic = getImage(getCodeBase(), "CarDash.jpg");
    horn = new Rectangle(250, 142, 105,104);
    vent = new Rectangle(514, 159, 204, 72);
    doorLocksUpper = new Rectangle(80, 167, 104, 58);
    window = new Rectangle(122, 243, 88, 55);
    radio = new Rectangle(514, 234, 176, 171);
    ignition = new Rectangle(465, 217, 42, 43);

    directions = new JLabel("CLICK ON: Horn, Door Locks, Air Vents, Radio & Ignition Push Start");

    //Create components
    contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contentPane.add(directions, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.addMouseListener(this);
}


//Display image on applet window
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(pic, 0, 40, this);

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    //Play horn clip when car horn is clicked.
    if(horn.contains(me.getX(), me.getY())) {
        play(getCodeBase(), "HornSound.wav");
    }
    if(vent.contains(me.getX(), me.getY())) {
        play(getCodeBase(), "AirVent.wav");
    }
    if(ignition.contains(me.getX(), me.getY())) {
        play(getCodeBase(), "Ignition.wav");
    }
    if(doorLocksUpper.contains(me.getX(), me.getY())) {
        play(getCodeBase(), "DoorLocks.wav");
    }
    if(radio.contains(me.getX(), me.getY())) {
        play(getCodeBase(), "BrownSugar.mid");
    }
    if(window.contains(me.getX(), me.getY())) {
        play(getCodeBase(), "Window.wav");
    }
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a really quick and useful tip, don't paint directly to a top level container like a applet.  It traps you into a single use case, which doesn't always make it easier to modify or re-use.

Instead, start by using something like a `JPanel` as your primary container, with this, you can add it to what ever you like, applet, window, some other container.

While there are a number of ways you can do animation in Swing, one of the simplest (and generally safest) is to use a Swing `Timer`.

This example simply uses a Swing `Timer`, set to update every 16ms (which is to fast for my capture software :P) which is started when you click the panel.  The timer simply updates a offset value which isolates between a positive and negative value.  The `Timer` makes use of `LocalTime` to calculate the length of time the `Timer` has been running at stops it after one second

[image: Shake it up baby]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ShakeAnimation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ShakeAnimation();
    }

    public ShakeAnimation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ShakePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ShakePane extends JPanel {

        private Timer timer;
        private LocalTime startTime;
        private int xOffset = 0;
        private int delta = 8;

        private BufferedImage img;

        public ShakePane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Duke-Thumbs.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            timer = new Timer(16, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, LocalTime.now());
                    if (duration.getSeconds() >= 1) {
                        timer.stop();
                        xOffset = 0;
                    } else {
                        xOffset *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                        xOffset = delta;
                        startTime = LocalTime.now();
                        timer.start();
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = ((getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2) + xOffset;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

See [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed help!  Quick question.  I didn't understand what you meant by "don't paint directly to a top level container like a applet. It traps you into a single use case".  When you say use a JPanel, do I create a regular swing window like a JFrame and JPanel and you're talking about using that instead of Content Pane?  In a case like that would I no longer be using the Applet Viewer?  This assignment wants us to use JApplet.  I didn't know if you could use all the swing components w/ JApplet like JPanel and if I'd need to extend JFrame...

Comment: No, in this case, you can add the `JPanel` to what ever you (like a `JApplet`), it just moves the responsibility to a better level of management. First, top level containers (like `JApplet`) aren't double buffered, so you might get some flicker or other graphics glitch and `JApplet` (and `JFrame`) have a `JRootPane` and `contentPane` between the physical container and the user, since you've actually broken the paint chain, this could further introduce the potential for graphics glitches

Comment: Thanks Mad!  If you see this and have a sec.. what do you mean by "you've actually broken the paint chain"?

Comment: In Swing painting is performed by a series of chained method calls, starting with `paint`, which calls a series of sub methods, by not call `super.paint`, you've actually circumvented this system and broken the paint chain. Because of the way painting can work, child components can be painted independently of the parent container under some circumstances (mouse over for example), which could result in no end of weirdness.

Comment: Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details